# How do I serialize/deserialize Jint engine into string/file

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

Would it be possible to serialize Jint JS engine into a string or a file, and deserialize and load it at a later point? if this is not possible with Jint, is it possible with any other .NET JavaScript interpreters?

Comment: what exactly you want to serialize/deserialize? do you mean JSON serialization?

Comment: The execution context.